# Como ativar/desativar uma Div quando clicar no checkBox

Tags: javascript, html

Como ativar e desativar uma `div` ao clicar no `checkbox`

```js
$("#chkBloqueio").click(function() {
  if ($("#chkBloqueio").attr('checked') == true) {
    $("#divBloqueio").attr('display', 'inline');
  } else {
    $("#divBloqueio").attr('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divBloqueio" runat="server" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Olá @Matheus. Precisa dar mais detalhe na sua questão: o que pretende, quais as dificuldades, etc, caso contrário não conseguiremos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Defina "desativar". Seria esconder ela? Remover ela do DOM? Tornar todos os `<input>` dentro dela `disabled`?

Comment: O "ativar/desativar" seria tornar visível no DOM, quanto o checkBox for marcado a Div ficara display:inline. (Desculpa por não ter esclarecido inicialmente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
$('#chkBloqueio').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#divBloqueio').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        $("#divBloqueio").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Seria mais performático usar `if (this.checked)` pois não precisaria converter para um objeto jQuery e é nativo.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.